# IF Statement Checking (Not Working Properly)

Tags: java, arrays, loops, if-statement, boolean

`randomEmpty()` returns a random coordinate on the n x n grid that is empty (Method works). `randomAdjacent()` uses `randomEmpty()` to select an EMPTY coordinate on the map. Comparisons are then made to see if this coordinate has an VALID adjacent coordinate that is NON-EMPTY. The PROBLEM is that `randomAdjacent` does not always return the coordinates of space with an adjacent NON-EMPTY space. It will always return valid coordinates but not the latter. I can't spot the problem. Can someone help me identify the problem?

```
public int[] randomEmpty()
{
    Random r = new Random();
    int[] random = new int[2];
    int row = r.nextInt(array.length);
    int column = r.nextInt(array.length);
    while(!(isEmpty(row,column)))
    {
        row = r.nextInt(array.length);
        column = r.nextInt(array.length);
    }
    random[0] = row+1;
    random[1] = column+1;
    return random;        
}

public int[] randomAdjacent()
{
    int[] adjacentToX = new int[8];
    int[] adjacentToY = new int[8];
    int[] adjacentFrom = randomEmpty();
    int count;
    boolean isTrue = false;
    boolean oneAdjacentNotEmpty = false;

    while(!(oneAdjacentNotEmpty))
    {
        count = 0;

        if(validIndex(adjacentFrom,1,-1))
        {
            adjacentToX[count] = adjacentFrom[0]+1;
            adjacentToY[count] = adjacentFrom[1]-1;
            count++;
        }
        if(validIndex(adjacentFrom,0,-1))
        {               
            adjacentToX[count] = adjacentFrom[0];
            adjacentToY[count] = adjacentFrom[1]-1;
            count++;
        }
        if(validIndex(adjacentFrom,-1,-1))
        {          
            adjacentToX[count] = adjacentFrom[0]-1;
            adjacentToY[count] = adjacentFrom[1]-1;
            count++;
        }
        if(validIndex(adjacentFrom,-1,0))
        {        
            adjacentToX[count] = adjacentFrom[0]-1;
            adjacentToY[count] = adjacentFrom[1];
            count++;
        }
        if(validIndex(adjacentFrom,-1,1))
        {       
            adjacentToX[count] = adjacentFrom[0]-1;
            adjacentToY[count] = adjacentFrom[1]+1;
            count++;
        }
        if(validIndex(adjacentFrom,0,1))
        {         
            adjacentToX[count] = adjacentFrom[0];
            adjacentToY[count] = adjacentFrom[1]+1;
            count++;
        }
        if(validIndex(adjacentFrom,1,1))
        {         
            adjacentToX[count] = adjacentFrom[0]+1;
            adjacentToY[count] = adjacentFrom[1]+1;
            count++;
        }
        if(validIndex(adjacentFrom,1,0))
        {        
            adjacentToX[count] = adjacentFrom[0]+1;
            adjacentToY[count] = adjacentFrom[1];
            count++;
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            if(!(isEmpty(adjacentToX[i],adjacentToY[i])))  
            {
                oneAdjacentNotEmpty = true;
                isTrue = true;
            }
        }
        if(isTrue)
            break;
        else
            adjacentFrom = randomEmpty();           
    }
    return adjacentFrom;
}

public boolean validIndex(int[] a,int i, int j)
{
    try
    {
        Pebble aPebble = array[a[0]+i][a[1]+j];
        return true;
    }
    catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
public void setCell(int xPos, int yPos, Pebble aPebble)
{
    array[xPos-1][yPos-1] = aPebble;
}

public Pebble getCell(int xPos, int yPos)
{
    return array[xPos-1][yPos-1];
}
```

JUNIT Test Performed:

```
@Test
public void testRandomAdjacent() {
    final int size = 5;
    final Board board2 = new Board(size);
    board2.setCell(1, 1, Pebble.O);
    board2.setCell(5, 5, Pebble.O);
    int[] idx = board2.randomAdjacent();
    int x = idx[0];
    int y = idx[1];
    boolean empty = true;
    for (int i = x - 1; i <= x + 1; i++) {
        for (int j = y - 1; j <= y + 1; j++) {
            if ((i == x && j == y) || i < 1 || j < 1 || i > size || j > size) {
                continue;
            }
            if (board2.getCell(i, j) != Pebble.EMPTY)
                empty = false;
        }

    }
    assertFalse(empty);// NEVER gets SET TO FALSE
    assertEquals(Pebble.EMPTY, board2.getCell(x, y));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for the answer: I got carried away optimizing your code for readability. I'd think  it's most likely

```
if (board2.getCell(i, j) != Pebble.EMPTY)
            empty = false;
```

causing the problem as getCell operates in 1-based coordinates, but i, j are in 0-based.

You should think about your logic overall. The way I see it, your code might never terminate as randomEmpty() could keep returning the same field over and over again for an undetermined period of time.

I took the liberty to recode your if-if-if cascade into utility method easier to read:

```
public boolean hasNonEmptyNeighbor(int[] adjacentFrom) {
    for(int i = -1; i <= 1; ++i) {
      for(int j = -1; j <= 1; ++j) {
        if(validIndex(adjacentFrom, i, j) //Still inside the board
             &&                           // AND
           !isEmpty(adjacentFrom[0]+i     //not empty
                      ,adjacentFrom[1]+j)) {
          return true;
        }
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
```

Given my previous comment about random() being not the best of choices if you need to cover the full board, your main check (give me an empty cell with a non-empty neighbor) could be rewritten like this:

```
  public void find() {
     List<Point> foundPoints = new ArrayList<Point>();
     for(int i = 0; i < Board.height; ++i) { //Assumes you have stored your height
       for(int j = 0; j < Board.width; ++j) { //and your width
         if(isEmpty(i, j) && hasNonEmptyNeighbor(new int[]{i,j})) {
            //Found one.  
            foundPoints.add(new Point(i, j));
         }
       }
     }
     //If you need to return a RANDOM empty field with non-empty neighbor
     //you could randomize over length of foundPoints here and select from that list.
   }
```

Comment: Thanks @Jan. I knew I could of condensed my if statements but I chose to cut corner because I was thinking from one approach instead of others. I do need to return a Random empty field with non-empty neighbor for $find()$ but that should be easy to do.